# Domain name registrar performance or rather differences?

Tags: performance, dns

Does it make a difference in performance at which domain name registrar I register a domain?

As an example, DigitalOcean does not offer a domain registration but what does this comparison at https://www.dnsperf.com/ show?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing completely different things.

You have at least the following roles:

- a domain name registrar, connecting to domain name registries to provision domain names, and at least maintain a whois server, besides its web interface (and optional API) to let clients act on their domain names
- a DNS provider, allowing any domain to use its nameservers and providing clients ways (website, API) to change the records served in their zone by the provider nameserver
- a webhosting company, providing webservers for clients to server their content (dynamic or static)

(and you can have even more of them, but unrelated, like CDN provider, X.509 certificates seller, domain name marketplace, etc.)

You seem to mix at least the first two points.

It is difficult to define the "performance" of a pure domain name registrar. You come to it to buy a domain name, and that is all. How its website and whois server works have no operational consequences on your domain name, and you may need to come again to its website only if you need to do some changes, like on contacts and nameservers, but maybe nothing at all, and just one year after creation come again to renew the domain (or even not that if you already bought it for like 10 years like it is possible in gTLDs). You can always judge its customer service I guess, but that will be highly subjective.

On the other hand, a DNS provider has to provide a constant service as its nameservers must reply properly at all time for your domain name. So you can assess their availability worldwide, their time to reply, the time it takes to see them updated after a change you made in the zone (and how you provision the zone), how they react under a DDOS for your domain or for other domains they make host but which could impact you as well, etc.

So

> Does it make a difference in performance at which domain name registrar I register a domain?

Probably no, but, replace *domain name registrar* by *DNS provider* and then the answer is probably yes.